# Rotating around X affects Roll. How to eliminate this?

Tags: android, sensors, pitch, rotational-matrices

I'm using android's TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR sensor to determine rotation around x,y and z and use these measures in my application in a certain way. But when I rotate phone around X axis, roll value (rotation around Y) also changes. And I don't want that. How can I ignore changes in roll when I rotate around X? Here is piece of my code

```
private final float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] orientationVals = new float[3];

if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {

             SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(
                     mRotationMatrix , event.values);
             SensorManager.getOrientation(mRotationMatrix, orientationVals);

             azimuthVal =  (Math.round((Math.toDegrees(orientationVals[0]))*100.0)/100.0);
             pitchVal= (Math.round((Math.toDegrees(orientationVals[1]))*100.0)/100.0);
             rollVal = (Math.round((Math.toDegrees(orientationVals[2]))*100.0)/100.0);
             }
```